# How to model preference from observed selection frequencies

Tags: probability

I am struggling how to model preference from given selection frequencies/probabilities in a probabilistic way.

**Example**: Alice likes Bob and wants to give him candy that he likes. Because it should be a surprise, Alice cannot ask Bob which candy he likes. Instead, Alice decides to observe what type of candy Bob eats. She observes him for one week and counts

|  | Red candy | Green candy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selected | 3 | 7 |

Alice's first solution is *green*, because Bob selected more green candy and Alice likes maximum likelihood solutions.
However, then Alice realizes that not all candy types were available in the same quantity. Alice doesn't remember exactly which candy types were available at which occasion and which choice Bob made, but at least she recalls how often each type was available in total:

|  | Red candy | Green candy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Available | 3 | 97 |
| Selected | 3 | 7 |

Alice's second solution is *red* since Bob selected 3 out of 3 red, which is larger than 7 out of 97 green.

But still, Alice isn't sure. After all, Bob selected more green than red. Maybe Bob didn't even know how many were available of each type. So Alice tries to find a way to combine both solutions in a meaningful way. Alice doesn't know Bob that well and is a bit confused and thus has no specific prior knowledge as to whether Bob's choice depends on the number of available candies or not.

**Question**: What is a meaningful way to model this situation s.t. Alice can estimate  Bob's preference? We are given a multiset $m=(C,D)=(\{A,B,...\},(n_A,n_B,...))$ with $|C|=n$ unique elements, an outcome $s\subset m$, and need to estimate the MLE/MAP for the probability of observing each unique element in the outcome. Surely, the frequencies in the outcome are limited by those in $m$, but we don't know there is a further dependence. We could do a direct estimation based on the frequencies in $m$, or based on the frequencies in $s$, but if we don't know which frequencies matter, can we somehow combine both scenarios, e.g., based on a prior belief?